# Probability of selecting a type of chocolate

Tags: probability

The probability of selecting a white chocolate from a box is 
1/5 and the probability of selecting a dark chocolate from the same box is 
1/3. The other chocolates are milk chocolates. 
a) Find the probability of selecting a milk chocolate. 
b) How many chocolates in total could be in the box? Give reasons. Is there more than one answer?

Answer (score 1):

Hint -

(1) Probabilities of all event equal to 1. So you can probability of milk chocolates by subtracting the sum of other two probabilities from 1.

(2) Total chocolates are in multiples. So we can't find exact value.